# Change the html in my webView

Tags: iphone, html, webview, modal-dialog

I want to change the .html in my webView from my modalViewController, but not always the same, I mean, I want to know some function that can tell me wich .html is in the screen, so I can change it for the next one, like a modalView controller but with .html files. Can I do that?

Comment: I didn't know i had to do that, sorry... i'm really new on this. It's done, thank you for the info ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the webview delegates methods to accomplish that

To know what html file is being called, use

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

and to know which url is being called you could do something like

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"my url is %@", url);

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

```
NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

NSLog(@"my url is %@", url);

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Be sure to format your code, as written it is too difficult to read

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.